# laravel elequent query with multiple conditions based on user search/filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to retrieve all rows in my table, but with user filters(where conditions).

Table looks like this:
`news: id, category, type, body, is_active`

I want the user to filter them by: `type` and `is_active`

So i am using

`if(Input::get("is_active")) 
    News::where("is_active", 1)->get();`

`if(Input::get("type")) 
    News::where("type", Input::get("type"))->get();`

`if(Input::get("category")) 
    News::where("category", Input::get("category"))->get();`

How can I run **all conditions** on the same query? I don't want to make if/else for each condition and re-write the query all over again!

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
$query = News::newQuery();

if(Input::get("is_active")) 
    $query->where("is_active", 1)->get();

if(Input::get("type")) 
    $query->where("type", Input::get("type"))->get();

if(Input::get("category")) 
    $query->where("category", Input::get("category"))->get();

return $query->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
News::where("is_active", 1)
    ->where('type', Input::get("type"))
    ->where('category', Input::get("category"))
    ->get();
```

or if you want only active news with other or conditions.

```
News::where("is_active", 1)
    ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('type', Input::get("type"))
                  ->where('category', Input::get("category"))
        })->get();
```

Check out [advanced where](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a closure to `where()`

**Try this:**

```
$filters = ['is_avtive', 'type', 'category'];

News::where(function($q) use ($filters){

    foreach($filters as $field)
        $q->where($field, Input::get($field));

})->get();
```